# Item Menu can't be registered in Home Page

Tags: menu-item, joomla-3.5

When I try to create the Home item for the menu on the Home-Page of my site, it isn't possible. I receive this warning message:

"Save failed with the following error: Another menu item has the same alias in Root (remember it may be a trashed item). Root is the top level parent."

[image]

I have 2 more items registered in that menu (with linked single articles), and these two items are displayed correctly in the front-page of my website.

**SOLVED:** It's only possible to register one unique Home item menu (with unique item alias at current level) for all the set of the items registered at that moment in out Joomla site.

source: https://books.google.es/books?id=tsfYKoWX1ncC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=unique+name+item+menu+joomla&source=bl&ots=xBsdV52aMv&sig=rsVhgcwwMfQuHJ3viPcoKxKPe7I&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipvKrSs-jMAhXDMBoKHZBxBnsQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=unique%20name%20item%20menu%20joomla&f=false

Book "Using Joomla: Building Powerful and Efficient Web Sites", Menu Item Manager, page 83

Comment: Welcome to JSE :) I'm glad you found a solution, but could you post that solution as an answer please (instead of putting it in your question).

Answer (score 1):

check all of your menu items alias' make sure none of them share the same name as your home page, look in trash too.

Joomla wont let you have two menu items with the same name at root level

Answer (score 1):

you have to look in menu items- search-tools- select status, and select the option trashed

select the item home and  look for the button -empty trash- and click

that will delete your menu item "home" and you can could create it again

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here there is or was an alias that shared the same name. Once this has been found figure out which menu this should actually go into. Now it sounds like you have another menu that you would like to have a home menu to as well, but you don't want to have two different "home" "home2" pages, not a problem, on the second menu go ahead and click add new menu item, System Links, Menu Item Alias.  You can name this whatever you would like, but the jist of it is that it will still revert back to your original home page, and have the correct seo in the URL String. In alot of cases I will actually have my main menu in the footer of the page, with aliases in the "main menu" bar of my template. This way I can keep better track of them, and I can point the Google Robots to find the main menu at the bottom of the page with a little code.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: It's only possible to register one unique Home item menu (with unique item alias at current level) for all the set of the items registered at that moment in out Joomla site.

source: https://books.google.es/books?id=tsfYKoWX1ncC&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=unique+name+item+menu+joomla&source=bl&ots=xBsdV52aMv&sig=rsVhgcwwMfQuHJ3viPcoKxKPe7I&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipvKrSs-jMAhXDMBoKHZBxBnsQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=unique%20name%20item%20menu%20joomla&f=false

Book "Using Joomla: Building Powerful and Efficient Web Sites", Menu Item Manager, page 83